# Can't use lambda function in Jade/Pug template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, editor, webstorm

I have a Node.JS app that I am building WebStorm.  I have my Javascript language setting for the project set to **ECMAScript 6**.  I can put code like that below successfully in any of my server side Javascript files, without getting errors from the editor:

```
g_CurrentChat.on('message', (message) => {
    // Show the message.
    renderMessage(message);
});
```

However, if I try to add the *exact* same code (cut and paste) into a *.script* block of a Pug/Jade template (*.JADE extension) the editor highlights the "**=>**" operator with the error "*expression expected*".

How can I get the editor to recognize the lamba function as valid syntax?

Comment: Please follow this issue on the WebStorm tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32306